# Remove a directory from path with Regex .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url:

`http://www. my site .com/cms/forum/users/username/`

I need it to redirect to:

`http://www. my site .com/forum/users/username/`

So the cms part of the url needs to go away. What is my regex, and where in the folder structure do I put it? In other words do I add this regex to the `.htaccess` in the root of the site or in the `.htaccess` in the `cms` folder or someplace else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for this task

```
RedirectMatch /cms(/.*) $1
```

You can also give a status to it, for example

```
RedirectMatch 301 /cms(/.*) $1
```

From the manual

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

This means, you can use it in your main server config, the virtual host config for your site or in the .htaccess file, wherever it fits best.